# Cant solve pre-beginner level python exercise

Tags: python

I am just learning python and using codecademy to learn basics but im stuck in an exercise, hoping you guys could hep with.

The course first wants me to define a function called `compute_bill` and give it one arguement which is `food`.
Then give `total` an initial value of `0` and then for each `item` in `food` list add their value to `total` and finally return `total`.

this is the prewritten list of prices and stock numbers.

```
shopping_list = ["banana", "orange", "apple"]

stock = {
    "banana": 6,
    "apple": 0,
    "orange": 32,
    "pear": 15
}

prices = {
    "banana": 4,
    "apple": 2,
    "orange": 1.5,
    "pear": 3
}
```

and this is the little function that i wrote but course is not accepting it saying **compute_bill(['apple']) resulted in a TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'**

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for item in food:
        total += item
    return total
```

it might be a very stupid question for most of you but i just cant understand what's the problem with it.

Comment: Well, if you're calling it as `compute_bill(['apple']) ` you're trying to add `'apple'` and `0`.

Comment: The error says it all, you are adding int ( total = 0) and a string ( item in food ) . Change **total += item** to **total += prices[item]**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a couple of mistakes:

1) "food" is a list. Every element there is a string. You can't add a string to a number in Python (and it wouldn't make sense).

2) What you really want to do is to use elements from "food" as keys, and then get prices from "prices" which is a dictionary.

One hint: to get a value for an element 'apple' from prices, you have to do something like:

```
apple_price = prices['apple']
```

This will give you the entry from 'prices' stored under the key 'apple', which is an integer equal 2. You can use this price to calculate the total.

Another hint: iterate over the elements in "food" and use these elements to retrieve corresponding prices from "prices" dictionary.

Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it. The for loop is iterating through each string in the food[] array, with that string you need to lookup the price in the prices dictionary.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in food:
        total += prices[key]
    return total
```

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to give full solution to someone who should come to it by himself ...

Answer (score 1):

I wish i could give you all an upvote. Thanks a lot for answers and advices i've just seen how silly i am.

```
def compute_bill(food):
    total = 0
    for key in food:
        total += prices[key]
    return total
```

this just did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 total += prices[item]
```

The code in the question is not referring to prices at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
def compute_bill(food) :
    total = 0
    for item in food :
        if stock[item] != 0 :
            total = total + prices[item]
            #you also need to update the stock table i won't do it here
    return total

food = {"banana","apple","orange"}
print compute_bill(food)
```